# Make Updates to an Old Windows Service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, service, windows-services

I am looking to update an old Windows Service which has been running for a couple years now with no interruption. I have updated a couple connection strings within the project, and everything seems to build fine.

Is there a way to update this service without having to uninstall and reinstall? I would rather not uninstall considering how long it has been running in a stable state.

Could I simply just Stop the Service, replace the re-built EXE and re-start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the required settings in the registry are not different you should be fine.

If possible test first on another machine.